# Ellipsis in Firefox without going to Mozilla.org

Tags: firefox, css

In order to get ellipsis to work in Firefox, I need to create an extra XML file that makes several references to Mozilla.org to get the Firefox to recognize the CSS3 text-overflow feature.

```
<bindings xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl" xmlns:xbl="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl" xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
```

However, if possible, I will like to not having to refer Mozilla.org at all if I can get all the definitions locally on the web servers just in case if the web servers blacklist Mozzila.org. 
And curiously  ***"http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"*** returns a 404 error but the xmlns is definitely required, otherwise ellipsis will not work.

Please let me know if anyone has a better solution.

Thanks, 
badallen

Comment: Note that this trick will not work in Firefox 4 (and does not work in recent betas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url is really just an identifier that is unique.  The fact it looks like a url is just because that is an easy way to create an unique identifier.